# File size in vb.net

Tags: vb.net

In Form1 I have a Textbox1, in this textbox I have the location of a file "C:\folder\file.iso"

In the Form2 I want to get the file size of the file in Textbox1 so I tried this

```
        Dim fileDetail As IO.FileInfo


    fileDetail = My.Computer.FileSystem.GetFileInfo(Form1.Textbox1.Text)

    Label1.Text = Size: fileDetail.Length
End Sub
```

I dont get an error, but the size of the file isn't showed in the label.

Edit: This doesn't seem to work

```
Private Sub Unscramble_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    If System.IO.File.Exists(Form1.TextBox2.Text) Then
        Dim fi As New System.IO.FileInfo(Form1.TextBox2.Text)
        Label3.Text = "Size: " & fi.Length.ToString()
    End If
End Sub
```

It still doesn't give me the size of the file nor it gives the "Size:"

Comment: Are you really sure you want that event attached to form load rather than a button click?

Comment: Yes, because this form will popup when the "convert" process is done.

Comment: so the File in the TextBox does not exist! :) set a breackpoint in the line with if condition and test your "Textbox1.Text" file existence.

Comment: sorry, but really, what do you do? Why in the Load method you test it? Why do you use Form1.TextBox, have you initialized a shared textbox on the Form1 class? **replace temporary the `Form1.TextBox2.Text` with `"C:\boot.ini"` and see what happens.**

Comment: Ok i made a textbox in the current form: Unscramble and it gave me the size 

Dim fileDetail = My.Computer.FileSystem.GetFileInfo(Textbox1.Text)
    Label1.Text = "Size : " & fileDetail.Length

But when i want the location of the file in a textbox in another form it gives me an error

Dim fileDetail = My.Computer.FileSystem.GetFileInfo(form1.Textbox1.Text)
    Label1.Text = "Size : " & fileDetail.Length

Comment: I try to decode what have you wrote: You have a texbox in the Unscramble form. I didn't understand anything else...sorry

Comment: Sorry, i'm very new to coding/vb.net. 

It works when i have the textbox inside the unscramble form.
But when i use the Textbox inside of Form1 it gives me an error.

You said something about making the textbox shared so the unscramble form can see it. How can i do this?

Comment: see my edit in the answer. is it's anything unclear, ask.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
    Dim fileDetail = My.Computer.FileSystem.GetFileInfo(form1.Textbox1.Text)
    Label1.Text = "Size : " & fileDetail.Length
```

Answer (score 2):

```
' this is the first(main) form'
Public Class Form1

  Private Sub Button1_Click( _
      ByVal sender As System.Object, _
      ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

    ' create the form2 by PASSING it the file path in constructor'
    Dim f2 As New Form2(TextBox1.Text)
    f2.ShowDialog()
  End Sub
End Class

' this is the second form'
Public Class Form2
  Inherits Form
  Private _filePath As String
  Private Label1 As Label

  Public Sub New(ByVal filePath As String)
    _filePath = filePath
  End Sub

  ' this is the _Load method of the second form'
  Protected Overrides Sub OnLoad(ByVal e As System.EventArgs)
    MyBase.OnLoad(e)

    If IO.File.Exists(_filePath) Then
      Dim fi As New IO.FileInfo(_filePath)
      Label1.Text = "Size :" & fi.Length.ToString()
    End If
  End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: what do you mean? what is the `fi.Length` value?

Answer (score 0):

Code works perfect but something in my project is blocking it.

Created a new project and it worked perfect.

Answer (score 0):

```
'label3.Text is my all string with file size.

Label3.Text = "Size : " & My.Computer.FileSystem.GetFileInfo("C:\Download\my song.mp3").Length & " Bytes"
'Output: Size: 2344 Bytes

Label3.Text = "Size : " & System.Math.Round(My.Computer.FileSystem.GetFileInfo("C:\Download\my song.mp3").Length / 1024) & " KB"
'Output: Size: 2 KB
```

There is two choice, Which you want