# How to get text from form1

Tags: .net, vb.net

I have 2 forms. In form1 i have a textbox called TextBox1
In Form2 i have another textbox called TextBox2.

I want the text from textbox1 to textbox2, i tried this.

```
TextBox2.Text = Form1.TextBox1.Text
```

Do i need to make changes to the first textbox?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Joel mentioned you will need to make the `TextBox` control public, be default they are `Friend` which allows other classes/controls/forms in the same Assembly (VB.NET Project) to access the control but not classes/controls/forms from outside the Assembly.

The change can be made in two ways, in the GUI Designer or the generated code.

To make the change in the designer:

- Select the TextBox
- Go to the Properties window (or right-click and select "Properties")
- Change the "Modifiers" property to "Public"

To change the generated code you will need to:

- enable "Show All Files" in the Solution Explorer
- Right-click the Form's .Designer.vb file and select "View Code"
- Locate the TextBox's declaration, which will be like:

  Friend WithEvents TextBox1 As Windows.Forms.TextBox

Change "Friend" to "Public"

```
Public WithEvents TextBox1 As Windows.Forms.TextBox
```

***On a side-note*** This works fine, but is generally not a good practice to have controls "reaching into" other controls to get/set values.  I understand you're new to .net so I'll spare the details, but once you feel you've tackled the initial learning curve you'll want to read into the ideas behind the MVC / MVP / MVVM / MV* patterns--they focus on seperation of logic and UI

Comment: Made the changes, its on public but i get an error saying 

System.ArgumentNullException: Argument cannot be Nothing.
Parameter name: file

TextBox2 on form1 has text in it so i dont get it.

Comment: that argument indicates the error is on a method call that requires a parameter, which doesn't sound like it's related to reading the text value.  In Visual Studio, try pressing "Ctrl-Alt-E" and placing a checkmark in the box under "Thrown" next to "Common Language Runtime Exceptions".  This will take you to the offending code right when the exception occurs.

Comment: Would you my taking a look at the code? I created a new project to test it and everything works perfect, but on this project it doesnt seem to work. If u want to take a look at it contact me on tonversteeg1@gmail.com

Comment: if you have a working and non-working version then you should be able to whittle down the differences and solve it yourself.  Make a full copy of your non-working project (or check it into source control) so that you have a point to return to, then consolidate the differences one by one till you find it.

Answer (score 2):

Controls in windows forms are not public by default.  You either need to change the declaration of the TextBox on form1 to explicitly make it public or add a public property to form1 that gets and sets the textbox text (preferred) .

Comment: How can i do this? I'm very new to vb.net

Answer (score 1):

You will need to reference the instance of the form. Form1 is the class.

Comment: VB uses something called default form instance - often the "class" also _is_ the instance.

Answer (score 0):

As I already answered you in **[this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2070882/vb-net-file-size/2070895#2070895)** post you have all your code.

You should not access the `Form2.TextBox` **directly**, but to pass the textbox text as parameter in constructor OR via a public field (or property) of the second form.

This works, surely, if you **can**(and ***have necessary minimum knowledge of VB.NET*** in order to) modify the Form2 code.

If not, you should declare a unique (Shared in VB.NET) instance of Form2, that is make it `Public Shared myUniqueForm2 as Form2` then access the TextBox2 via `myUniqueForm2.TextBox2`

If the post are still unclear for you, you should stop asking people and read some short basic articles about Object Oriented Programming (OOP) and VB.NET.

By example **[this one](http://ondotnet.com/pub/a/dotnet/2001/09/25/oop_vb.html)** or *[this one](http://searchwindevelopment.techtarget.com/generic/0,295582,sid8_gci1223061,00.html)*.
A lot of tutorials about VB.NET you can find also *[here](http://www.programmingtutorials.com/vbnet.aspx)*.

Comment: The code works fine now, made some stupid mistake. the code was loaded before i had text in my textbox. Fixed it and it works perfect for me.